# Get the substring from a string in Apache drill using the position of a charecter

Tags: sql, apache-drill

Please help me with a solution.

From the string '/This/is/apache/drill/queries' I want a sql query that runs on Apache Drill to fetch sub-string 'drill' that comes after the 4th occurrence of '/'

NOTE: the length of the string varies, hence position of the '/' also varies. 
And the string starts with '/'

In drill the instr(string,'/',1,4) will not work. Hence I am not able to get the string that appears after the 4th occurrence of '/'.

Answer (score 4):

Drill has `split` UDF which does the same thing as `String.split()`, so this query:

```
SELECT split(a, '/')[4] FROM (VALUES('/This/is/apache/drill/queries')) t(a);
```

Will return the desired result:

```
+---------+
| EXPR$0  |
+---------+
| drill   |
+---------+
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use REGEXP_REPLACE for that purpose:

`SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('/This/is/apache/drill/queries', '^\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/(.*?)\/.*$.','\1');`

The above regular expression looks for fourth '/' and takes the content from there till fifth '/'.

Comment: Not so.  That query returns `/This/is/apache/drill/queries` when run on Drill and I don't believe that Drill's regexp_replace supports capture groups.

Comment: Good news: I was wrong about capture groups in Drill.  You can refer to them in the replacement string using `$1`, etc.